# Does the Catholic Church officially recognize Protestants as Christians?

Tags: catholicism, soteriology, protestantism, comparative-christianity, ecclesiology

I have always thought that the Pope did not recognize the validity of the faith of those outside of the Catholic church, but in comments from a different post I am surprised to find out I may be confused. It may be because I read old books and things have changed in more recent history.

Most Protestants believe that anyone who genuinely believes in Christ alone for the forgiveness of their sins is saved. I am one of them.  I believe simply believing in Christ without adding anything else to the mix, including church denomination, brings eternal life to anyone.

My question is does the Catholic church accept that Christians like me have eternal life, yes, or no? If so, when did the Catholic church begin to recognize the faith of those outside of her church and understand that as believers they will be in heaven?

I am not interested in if Catholicism recognizes my baptism, or other sacraments that may have been administered to me, but rather the eternal life which has been granted to me by believing in Jesus.   I am interested to know if my salvation as a whole, outside the Catholic church, is recognized by my trust in Chrst?

Comment: "Do Catholics officially recognize Protestants as Christians?" and "does the Catholic church accept that Christians like me have eternal life, yes, or no?" are actually two quite distinct questions whose answers don't quite align; for this reason, I'm voting to close this question as too broad.

Comment: I agree with bruisedreed and am voting to close for the same reason: which question are you asking?

Comment: In fact, a more fundamental question has to be answered first before answering this one: "[Who is a Christian?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/47172/1787)" Is he simply someone baptized, someone who is a member of the Mystical Body of Christ, or something else?

Comment: Have you read [Lumen Gentium](http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_const_19641121_lumen-gentium_en.html)?  If not, your research before asking the question is incomplete.    Read article 15 and see how that speaks to you.  Article 15 is under the general heading of "People of God."  You may wish to edit your question after reading that, or not.

Comment: @Geremia I think that's the same question: does the RCC officially recognize protestants as Christians according to their own definition of what a Christian is?

Comment: @curiousdannii The questions of membership in the Church and salvation are the same question?

Comment: @Geremia I don't understand what you mean or why you have a problem with this question.

Comment: @curiousdannii Whether one is a member of the Church is the same question as whether one will be saved?

Comment: @curiousdannii [_Mystici Corporis Christi_](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_29061943_mystici-corporis-christi.html) §23 clears up a common misconception that all the members of the Church are saved: "Nor must one imagine that the Body of the Church, just because it bears the name of Christ…consists only of those whom God has predestined to eternal happiness." Thus, the question of membership in the Church and the question of salvation are distinct.

Comment: @Geremia That all seems tangential to this question. This question is just asking whether Catholicism considers Protestants to be Christian by whatever definition of Christian it uses.

Comment: @curiousdannii He says: "my salvation as a whole, outside the Catholic church, is recognized by my trust in Chrst?" (a question of salvation) which is distinct from "Does the Catholic Church officially recognize Protestants as Christians?" (a question of membership).

Comment: Speaking as a Catholic, yes we do see all Protestants as Christians because they too see Christ as our savior. Do we see all of us who believe in Christ as saved? Not necessarily.  For example, how am I defining/interpreting the word "believe"? From my view, if I truly "believe", I'll act accordingly (i.e. as Jesus would expect me to vs. however I choose); subsequently, I still have His final judgement to pass.

Comment: "Very truly I tell you, whoever hears my word and believes him who sent me has eternal life and will not be judged but has crossed over from death to life" John 5:24

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From Catholic Answers article [*Does "no salvation outside the Church" include non-Catholic Christians?*](http://www.catholic.com/quickquestions/does-no-salvation-outside-the-church-include-non-catholic-christians), non-Catholic Christians are specifically addressed in the Catechism:

> The Church knows that she is joined in many ways to the baptized who
>   are honored by the name of Christian, but do not profess the Catholic
>   faith in its entirety or have not preserved unity or communion under
>   the successor of Peter. Those who believe in Christ and have been
>   properly baptized are put in a certain, although imperfect, communion
>   with the Catholic Church. With the Orthodox churches, this communion
>   is so profound that it lacks little to attain the fullness that would
>   permit a common celebration of the Lord’s Eucharist. [(CCC 838)](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p123a9p3.htm)

The way I read this, the answer is "yes, but they don't have the full Truth. If they've been properly baptized and believe in Christ, they are associated with the Church, but imperfectly."

This agrees with Catholic Answers article [*What is the relationship between the Church and baptized Protestants?*](http://www.catholic.com/quickquestions/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-church-and-baptized-protestants)

> **Full Question**
>
> What relationship does the Catholic Church perceive to exist between
>   itself and various Protestants (the baptized ones who still accept
>   their faith)?
>
> **Answer**
>
> Validly baptized Protestants are regarded as true Christian brothers
>   and sisters who are in imperfect relationship with the Church. The
>   nature of the imperfections is as varied as Protestantism itself. The
>   idea at work here is that the faith is an incarnational thing, not
>   just a "spiritual" (disembodied) thing—just like Jesus himself. Thus,
>   it is possible to be out of union with the Church "bodily"
>   (structurally, sacramentally, liturgically), yet still have a
>   spiritual unity with the Church. Likewise, it is possible to be
>   "bodily" united to the Church yet cease to be in communion with her
>   spiritually (as an apostate Catholic is if he keeps going to Communion
>   yet rejects the creed or continues unrepentant in grave sin). The
>   latter form of disunity with Church is more serious than the former.

Also, from EWTN Global Catholic Network article [*Some Things That Catholics Do Not Believe*](http://www.ewtn.com/library/ANSWERS/dontbelieve.HTM) (Item # 7):

> Catholics do not believe that Protestants who are baptized, who lead a good life, love God and their neighbor, and are blamelessly
>   ignorant of the just claims of the Catholic Religion to be the one
>   true Religion (which is called being in good faith), are excluded from
>   Heaven, provided they believe that there is one God in three Divine
>   Persons; *that God will duly reward the good and punish the wicked;
>   that Jesus Christ is the Son of God made man, who redeemed us, and in
>   whom we must trust for our salvation; and provided they thoroughly
>   repent of having ever, by their sins, offended God.
>
> Catholics hold that Protestants who have these dispositions, and who
>   have no suspicion of their religion being false, and no means to
>   discover, or fail in their honest endeavors to discover, the true
>   Religion, and who are so disposed in their heart that they would at
>   any cost embrace the Roman Catholic Religion if they knew it to be the
>   true one, are Catholics in spirit and in some sense within the
>   Catholic Church, without themselves knowing it. She holds that these
>   Christians belong to, and are united to the "soul," as it is called,
>   of the Catholic Church, although they are not united to the visible
>   body of the Church by external communion with her, and by the outward
>   profession of her faith.
>
> Very different is the case of a person who, having the opportunity,
>   neglects to learn from genuine trustworthy sources what the Catholic
>   Religion is and really teaches, fearing, that were he to become
>   convinced of the truth of the Catholic Faith, he would be compelled by
>   his conscience to forsake his own religion, and bear the worldly
>   inconveniences attached to this step. This very fear shows a want of
>   good faith, and that he is not in that insurmountable ignorance which
>   could excuse him in the sight of God, nut that he is one of those of
>   whom it is said in Psalm xxxv. 4, "He would not understand that he
>   might do well."
>
> Fairness, no less than common sense, teaches that a man should study
>   and examine the teaching of the Catholic Church from Catholic sources
>   before condemning her. Surely no man ought to reject Catholic doctrine
>   if he has not made himself well acquainted with them. Nor is is fair
>   to form a judgment from misrepresentations made by ill-informed,
>   interested, or prejudiced persons; one should rather, by the study of
>   authorized Catholic works, judge of the truth with that calm and
>   unprejudiced mind which the all-important subject of Religion
>   deserves. Thus having heard both sides, you will be in a state to pass
>   a right judgment and not in danger of being misled by prejudice.
>
> Our Saviour gave no hope of salvation to the Samaritan woman unless
>   she entered the one true Church of the tine, saying to her who was
>   destitute of a sure guide: "You adore that which you know not; we
>   adore that which we know; for SALVATION IS OF THE JEWS". (St John iv.
>   22.) So likewise there is no salvation for any one who, having by God's grace come to the knowledge of the truth, obstinately refuses to
>   join the true Church of God.

That third paragraph on, particularly the very last sentence, indicates to me that the hope of salvation for protestants doesn't extend to those that flat-out refuse to learn about what the Catholic Church really teaches.

Comment: The terms often used indicate that the Catholic Church and her sacraments are the "ordinary" means of salvation. Other means are not "guaranteed" by the Church, even though the Church "hopes" that God will also work "extraordinarily" through other groups' and person's beliefs and practices as well. Anyone who is ultimately heaven-bound is part of the mystical Church. Whether the Church on earth calls each person or denomination "Christian" would be case-by-case, I think.

Comment: So the answer would be "They ***hope*** non-Christians will get to heaven"?

Comment: @Mike - I found one more source - EWTN and added to this answer, which changes the final understanding significantly in my opinion.  It's less happy to find out.

Comment: @DavidStratton Your answer is sufficient. (+1) I only mean to add that the Church deems her own teachings and practices as the "ordinary" or "regular" means to serve God. Other means aren't condoned by the Church per se, but neither does the Church presume to think God can't work through other means. In all honesty, the Catholic answer to *anyone, a Catholic included*, asking whether they will be saved is, "We hope so."

Comment: @DavidStratton - thanks for all the good info. Now I am back to my original 'biased' view that basically it is doubtful to none, which explain the protestant equal reaction as doubtful to none that Catholics can be saved, for salvation depends on how sure one is that faith in Christ can save, not faith in church. Cheers

Comment: @Mike Are you saying "doubtful to none" because you think most protestants are not actually concerned with truth? Or because you interpreted this answer to mean that Catholic doctrine is unforgiving of non-Catholicism? If the latter, this answer should be revised to reflect the more "forgiving" attitude the Church teaches. And if the former ... Well, I'll assume you don't mean the former!

Comment: @svidgen - I mean that the Catholic church thinks many protestants who reject the proposed authority of the Catholic church have no reason for full assurance of salvation according to RC belief. i.e. little to none chances at being saved. I think I am understanding the that this answer more or less says so.

Comment: Based on Trent, I find this answer to be incorrect. The Council of Trent, which is still upheld by the vatican, specifically condemns and declares anathema anyone who has not been administered the sacraments in the Catholic method. This includes baptism and eucharest. It also declares anathema anyone who teaches differently than the Church about these sacraments, which is identically the protestant Church. So, either the Church's postition is self-conflicting or they declare Protestants condemned, but those are the only two possibilities.

Comment: That is, according to Trent, the only "proper" and "valid" baptism is a strictly Catholic one, and according to Trent, if anyone teaches or practices baptism or any other sacrament in any way than that prescribed by the Catholic church, or even differs in the number of sacraments practiced, he is cursed and condemned. See Trent Section 7 On Baptism Canon 3, and On Sacraments Canons 1,10, etc. In my opinion there is no getting around this. According to this document, which is still held as canon by the RCC, all protestants are condemned.

Comment: So the Catechism quoted in the answer is general info, and Trent info is more specific and pointed.

Comment: Seems to me like the answer is VERY incomplete w/o @Andrew 's reference to the applicable passages of the Council of Trent.  If it leads to a potential conclusion of a doctrinal self-conflict, so be it.  But if it is true that the RCC still holds the COT to be canon, then these passages should definitely be included in this answer.

Comment: Here are some other quotes that I find that support the conclusions made at the Council of Trent: "The Catholic Church alone is keeping the true worship. This is the font of truth, this is the house of faith, this is the temple of God; if any man enter not here, or if any man go forth from it, he is a stranger to the hope of life and salvation" - Pope Pius XI, Mortalium Animos

Comment: "Outside of the Church, nobody can hope for life or salvation unless he is excused through ignorance beyond his control." - Pope Pius IX, Singulari Quidem

Comment: "The most Holy Roman Church firmly believes, professes and preaches that none of those existing outside the Catholic Church, not only pagans, but also Jews and heretics and schismatics, can have a share in life eternal..."

Comment: "...but that they will go into the "eternal fire which was prepared for the devil and his angels" (Matthew 25:41), unless before death they are joined with Her; and that so important is the unity of this ecclesiastical body that only those remaining within this unity can profit by the sacraments of the Church unto salvation..."

Comment: "...and they alone can receive an eternal recompense for their fasts, their almsgivings, their other works of Christian piety and the duties of a Christian soldier. No one, let his almsgiving be as great as it may, no one, even if he pour out his blood for the Name of Christ, can be saved, unless he remain within the bosom and the unity of the Catholic Church." - 11th Session of the Council of Florence, under Pope Eugene IV

Comment: @David These are very unreliable sources, and they're false. Besides, the question is not asking about salvation of non-Catholics.

Comment: @Geremia The first quote from the catechism seems to address the question perfectly.

Comment: Two of the links are dead https://www.catholic.com/quickquestions/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-church-and-baptized-protestants https://www.ewtn.com/library/ANSWERS/dontbelieve.HTM

Answer (score 8):

That's funny to see that we all lack of information ([see my answer which asked exactly the opposite, that is to say if some protestant church believed that Catholics were pagans](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/are-catholics-like-pagans-in-evangelical-vision)).

In any case, reading the already mentioned [CCC 838](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/para/838.htm) and also other paragraphs, it's quite clear that Catholic church believes that everybody can find salvation if their heart sincerely searches for God

> Those who, through no fault of their own, do not know the Gospel of
> Christ or his Church, but who nevertheless seek God with a sincere
> heart, and, moved by grace, try in their actions to do his will as
> they know it through the dictates of their conscience - those too may
> achieve eternal salvation. (CCC 847)

Hence if through your faith you sincerely search for God, you are saved.

Be careful to some traps that we might fall in, like the one raised by the sentence

> "Outside the Church there is no salvation"

However, [CCC 846](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/para/846.htm) reveals the answer:

> 846 How are we to understand this affirmation, often repeated by the
> Church Fathers? Re-formulated positively, it means that all
> salvation comes from Christ the Head through the Church which is his
> Body:
>
> > Basing itself on Scripture and Tradition, the Council teaches that the Church, a pilgrim now on earth, is necessary for salvation: the one Christ is the mediator and the way of salvation; he is present to us in his body which is the Church. He himself explicitly asserted the necessity of faith and Baptism, and thereby affirmed at the same time the necessity of the Church which men enter through Baptism as through a door. **Hence they could not be saved who, knowing that the Catholic Church was founded as necessary by God through Christ, would refuse either to enter it or to remain in it**.

The last, bolded sentence, includes respect of God for our personality, thoughts, mentality. So if in your conscience you do not believe that the Catholic church is "founded as necessary by God through Christ", then you are still in the position of searching God with a sincere Heart.

Comment: Thanks for clarification it supplements the other post by David well.

Comment: The question isn't about salvation.

Comment: @Geremia How do you arrive at that position?

Answer (score 2):

Addressing your question of salvation: Is

> *my salvation as a whole, outside the Catholic church,…recognized by my trust in Christ?*

No, the Catholic Church, in the [Council of Trent session VI](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.i.i.iv.html), condemns the Protestant notion of *sola fide* ("saved by faith alone"):

> no one ought to flatter himself up with faith alone (*sola fide*), fancying that by faith alone (*sola fide*) he is made an heir [i.e., a member of the Church.]
>
> ---
>
> CANON IX.—If any one saith, that by faith alone (*sola fide*) the impious is justified, in such wise as to mean, that nothing else is required to cooperate in order to the obtaining the grace of Justification, and that it is not in any way necessary, that he be prepared and disposed by the movement of his own will: let him be anathema.

> *I have always thought that the Pope did not recognize the validity of the faith of those outside of the Catholic church*.

Yes, that's true—for example, Pope Eugene IV with the Council of Florence solemnly defined the following infallible (and thus unchangeable) dogma in *[Cantate Domino](http://catholicism.org/cantate-domino.html)*:

> The sacrosanct Roman Church, founded by the voice of our Lord and Savior…firmly believes, professes, and proclaims that **those not living within the Catholic Church**, not only pagans, but also Jews and heretics and schismatics **cannot become participants in eternal life**, but will depart “into everlasting fire which was prepared for the devil and his angels” [Matt. 25:41], **unless before the end of life the same have been added to the flock**; and that the unity of the ecclesiastical body is so strong that only to those remaining in it are the sacraments of the Church of benefit for salvation, and do fastings, almsgiving, and other functions of piety and exercises of Christian service produce eternal reward, and that no one, whatever almsgiving he has practiced, even if he has shed blood for the name of Christ, can be saved, unless he has remained in the bosom and unity of the Catholic Church.

<sub>A good book on this topic is Msgr. Joseph Clifford Fenton's [*The Catholic Church and Salvation: In the Light of Recent Pronouncements of the Holy See*](http://garrigou.us.to/browse/book/5299).</sub>

According to Pope Benedict XV's encyclical [*Ad Beatissimi Apostolorum*](https://w2.vatican.va/content/benedict-xv/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_ben-xv_enc_01111914_ad-beatissimi-apostolorum.html), a Christian is a Catholic who holds the faith in its entirety:

> 24. … Such is the nature of Catholicism that it does not admit of more or less, but must be held as a whole or as a whole rejected: "This is the Catholic faith, which unless a man believe faithfully and firmly; he cannot be saved" (Athanas. Creed). There is no need of adding any qualifying terms to the profession of Catholicism: it is quite enough for each one to proclaim "**Christian is my name and Catholic my surname**"

---

“Do Catholics officially recognize Protestants as Christians?" More generally: Are baptized non-Catholics Christians? No.

A Christian is someone who is a member of the Mystical Body of Christ. Baptized non-Catholics are not members of the Church because, as Pope Pius XII wrote in his encyclical *[Mystici Corporis Christi](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_29061943_mystici-corporis-christi.html)* §22:

> Actually only those are to be included as members of the Church who have
>
> 1. been baptized
>
> and
>
> 2. **profess the true faith**,*
>
> and
>
> 3. who have not been so unfortunate as to separate themselves from the unity of the Body, or been excluded by legitimate authority for grave faults committed.
>
> “For in one spirit” says the Apostle, “were we all baptized into one Body, whether Jews or Gentiles, whether bond or free.” As therefore in the true Christian community there is only one Body, one Spirit, one Lord, and one Baptism, so there can be only one faith. And therefore if a man refuse to hear the Church let him be considered — so the Lord commands — as a heathen and a publican. [cf. [Mt. 18:17](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=18&l=17-#x)] It follows that **those [who] are divided in faith or government cannot be living in the unity of such a Body, nor can they be living the life of its one Divine Spirit**.
> <sub>*[in its entirely; cf. *[Satis Cognitum](http://www.papalencyclicals.net/Leo13/l13satis.htm)*]</sub>

Protestants are at least [material heretic](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33902)s; they do not hold the same faith as Catholics. They deny the papacy, a truth necessary for being a member of the Church. They do not even recognize the visible Church (its government). And, as Pope Leo XIII said in *[Satis Cognitum](http://www.papalencyclicals.net/Leo13/l13satis.htm)*, an encyclical on the unity of the Church consisting in being “one in faith, in government, and in communion:”

> The practice of the Church has always been the same, as is shown by the unanimous teaching of the Fathers, who were wont to hold as **outside Catholic communion, and alien to the Church, whoever would recede in the least degree from any point of doctrine proposed by her authoritative Magisterium**.

Thus, Protestants are not Christian.

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer, but how would you reconcile your answer with [CCC 838](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p123a9p3.htm)?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple _CCC_ 838 cites Vatican II's [_Lumen Gentium_](http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_const_19641121_lumen-gentium_en.html) §15, which says the baptized "are honored with the Christian name" (_christiano nomine decorantur_); it in turn cites Pope Leo XIII's encyclical on the reunion of Christendom, [_Praeclara gratulationis_](http://www.vatican.va/content/leo-xiii/la/apost_letters/documents/hf_l-xiii_apl_18940620_praeclara-gratulationis.html),

Comment: @GratefulDisciple which says some "dissent from the Catholic belief, though they bear the name of Christians (_christiano initiata nomini_)." The sense is that they call themselves Christian. Neither document says baptized non-Cathloics must be or are truly called Christian. This accords with the Pope Benedict XV quote above: "Christian is my name and Catholic my surname."

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and reference.  I found an [unofficial English translation](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/leo13/l13praec.htm) for *Praeclara gratulationis*.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple The one I used comes from [_The Great Encyclical Letters of Pope Leo XIII (1878-1903)_](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=5898).

Answer (score -3):

“Do Catholics officially recognize Protestants as Christians?" More generally: Are baptized non-Catholics Christians?

The answer is no.

A Christian is someone who is a member of the Mystical Body of Christ. Baptized non-Catholics are not members of the Church because, as Pope Pius XII wrote in his encyclical *[Mystici Corporis Christi](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_29061943_mystici-corporis-christi.html)* §22:

> Actually only those are to be included as members of the Church who have
>
> 1. been baptized
>
> and
>
> 2. **profess the true faith**,*
>
> and
>
> 3. who have not been so unfortunate as to separate themselves from the unity of the Body, or been excluded by legitimate authority for grave faults committed.
>
> “For in one spirit” says the Apostle, “were we all baptized into one Body, whether Jews or Gentiles, whether bond or free.” As therefore in the true Christian community there is only one Body, one Spirit, one Lord, and one Baptism, so there can be only one faith. And therefore if a man refuse to hear the Church let him be considered — so the Lord commands — as a heathen and a publican. [cf. [Mt. 18:17](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=18&l=17-#x)] It follows that **those [who] are divided in faith or government cannot be living in the unity of such a Body, nor can they be living the life of its one Divine Spirit**.
> <sub>*[in its entirely; cf. *[Satis Cognitum](http://www.papalencyclicals.net/Leo13/l13satis.htm)*]</sub>

Protestants are at least [material heretic](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33902)s; they do not hold the same faith as Catholics. They deny the papacy, a truth necessary for being a member of the Church. They do not even recognize the visible Church (its government). And, as Pope Leo XIII said in *[Satis Cognitum](http://www.papalencyclicals.net/Leo13/l13satis.htm)*, an encyclical on the unity of the Church consisting in being “one in faith, in government, and in communion:”

> The practice of the Church has always been the same, as is shown by the unanimous teaching of the Fathers, who were wont to hold as **outside Catholic communion, and alien to the Church, whoever would recede in the least degree from any point of doctrine proposed by her authoritative Magisterium**.

Thus, Protestants are not Christian.

Comment: This answer basically takes some past statements from the church and applies your own interpretations to them, ignoring the official statements from the church about how they should be interpreted.

Comment: @djclayworth http://www.nowtheendbegins.com/pope-francis-says-christians-exist-outside-roman-catholic-church/.  Check this story out Pope says non Catholics are not christian

Comment: If you actually read what he says,  no he doesn't.

Comment: @DJClayworth "… _ignoring the official statements from the church about how they should be interpreted_" These are more official than what has been quoted in the other answers here. And what are the "official statements from the church about how" these statements "should be interpreted"?

Comment: "A Christian is someone who is a member of the Mystical Body of Christ." you are inferring this from somewhere, but it is a statement that is not directly supported by any of your quotes.  Is there actually an authoratitive Catholic definition of the word "Chrisitan"?

Comment: I suggest you reconsider your answer in the light of [#818 of the CCC](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p123a9p3.htm)

Comment: @Geremia *Your interpretation* of these statements is not more authoritative than the Catechism of the Catholic Church, which tells us how the Catholic Church interprets them.

Comment: @DJClayworth And how is "my interpretation" or what Popes Leo XIII and Pius XII say contrary to it?

Comment: @bruisedreed Encyclicals hold more weight than catechisms. And what would such an edit be? Saying Protestants are Christians in "a certain, although imperfect" sense (whatever that means)?

Comment: @bruisedreed Yes, I'm laying down the premise that "a Christian is someone who is a member of the Mystical Body of Christ." Who is a Christian is has to be resolved first before answering this SE question, and so far it hasn't been answered.

Comment: This: "...they therefore have a right to be called Christians, and with good reason are accepted as brothers in the Lord by the children of the Catholic Church" is **unambiguous**.  Are you seriously asserting that the encyclicals are contradicting the catechism and the latter is wrong?!

Comment: 'Saying Protestants are Christians in "a certain, although imperfect" sense'. Yes, that's exactly an edit that would make this a good answer and be in accordance with what the Catholic church teaches.

Comment: @bruisedreed To actually *be* "brothers in the Lord…of the Catholic Church" and to be "*accepted as* brothers in the Lord by the children of the Catholic Church" are two different things.

Comment: @DJClayworth What does "certain, although imperfect" even mean?

Comment: I've created us a chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36190/do-catholics-thing-protestants-are-christians