# Who is a Christian according to the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, baptism, ecclesiology, membership

How does the Catholic Church define who a Christian is? Is a Christian, according to the Catholic Church, someone who

1. is baptized,
2. a member of the Catholic Church or Mystical Body of Christ
3. something else?

Comment: When a Catholic uses the word Christian, he is referring to a person who was baptized into the Church Christ founded.  So if you were baptized in the Name of the Father, Son and Holy Spirit (or other valid baptisms)you are a Christian and have entered into the family of God.  Once entered into the family of God we are  obliged to fallow the instructions of those who have authority over us, they being the teaching authority of the Church,  the guardians of our souls. Remaining in the vine is still subject to free will, but those baptized are still children of God and considered Christians

Comment: @Marc Not [according to Pope Pius XII et al.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/47133/1787), who say that baptism, profession of the true Faith, and not being excommunicated are necessary for membership in the Church.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast If it's so easy, please post an answer. I have done much research.

Comment: @waxeagle: My question is asking nothing about Protestants, so how could it be a duplicate?

Comment: @Geremia Even when excommunicated you are a Christian, you are however not a Catholic Christian.  Did you mean to ask a different question?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast This question asked nothing about Protestants.

Comment: @Marc You're begging the question.

Comment: I'm sorry the very encyclical you use to support your assertions addresses the question in other sections of the same encyclical.  See for example Section 23 of MYSTICI CORPORIS CHRISTI.  Might I suggest that the manor in which you use sources of Catholic teachings may be the same method used by Protestants when they twist the scriptures to fit into their pre-conceived notions.  Our separated brethren are Christians who are in need of not only our Mercy, but that of Gods which most be offered above all else to those who search for him.

Comment: @Geremia what happens when you start down this path, it leads to becoming a Sedevacantist, which is more the falling away  of the souls of men then these other ecumenical  bodies who are coming towards mother Church.  Heresy comes from within the Church not from outside it.

Comment: @Marc Yes, [_Mystici Corporis Christi_](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_29061943_mystici-corporis-christi.html) §23 does clear up a common misconception that all the members of the Church are saved: "Nor must one imagine that the Body of the Church, just because it bears the name of Christ…consists only of those whom God has predestined to eternal happiness." That shows the question of membership in the Church and the question of salvation are distinct.

Comment: Of interest: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/20550/was-catholicism-the-first-denomination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Pope Benedict XV's encyclical [*Ad Beatissimi Apostolorum*](https://w2.vatican.va/content/benedict-xv/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_ben-xv_enc_01111914_ad-beatissimi-apostolorum.html), a Christian is a Catholic, who holds the faith in its entirety:

> 24. … Such is the nature of Catholicism that it does not admit of more or less, but must be held as a whole or as a whole rejected: "This is the Catholic faith, which unless a man believe faithfully and firmly; he cannot be saved" (Athanas. Creed). There is no need of adding any qualifying terms to the profession of Catholicism: it is quite enough for each one to proclaim "Christian is my name and Catholic my surname"…

Also, St. Gregory of Nyssa wrote a letter titled "What it Means to Call Oneself a Christian" ([*Ascetical Works*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8845) p[p. 79](https://archive.org/details/fathersofchurch0058unse/page/n9/mode/2up)-89); he shows that a Christian is one who conforms himself to Christ.

Comment: What do we make of someone who asks and answers his/her own question and marks it "best" to boot?  Funny or what?

Comment: @SLM Answering one's own question "[has always explicitly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)." See also: "[Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/257345)"

Comment: @SLM Many of us do this regularly.  Thankfully, the community's votes are what matter in such cases; accepting one's own answer doesn't make it the top answer.

Comment: @Geremia Is the set of baptized non-Catholic Christians empty?

Comment: @Thom ∃ baptized non-Catholics.

Comment: @Geremia Yes. I meant to ask, is there anyone whom we can call Christian among baptized non-Catholics? Or in other words, are there any Christians in the set of baptized non-Catholics?

Comment: @Thom Are you asking if heretics can be called Christian?

Comment: @Geremia So all baptized non-Catholics are heretics? Are the orthodox heretics too?

Comment: @Thom Yes, at least material heretics (cf. end of last ¶ of [this definition of heresy](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33902)). Yes, the Orthodox are at least material heretics, too, in addition to being schismatic (∵ they reject the office of the papacy).

Comment: @Geremia Interesting. Can they then be the members of the Church?

Comment: @Thom Pope Pius XII, encyclical [_Mystici Corporis Christi_ §22](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/47133/1787): "only those are to be included as members of the Church who have been baptized and profess the true faith, and who have not been so unfortunate as to separate themselves from the unity of the Body, or been excluded by legitimate authority for grave faults committed." Non-Catholics do not profess the true faith; ∴, they're not members of the Church.

Comment: @Geremia Then it follows from *Extra Ecclesiam nulla salus* that they (eg. protestants, orthodox) can not be saved unless they joined the Church?

Comment: @Thom To be saved, they must have at least an implicit desire to be members of the Church. See Msgr. Fenton's excellent [_The Catholic Church and Salvation: In the Light of Recent Pronouncements of the Holy See_](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5299). [This](https://hwcdn.libsyn.com/p/8/6/5/865c24022bdbd8c0/tradcast004.mp3?c_id=8687820&cs_id=8687820&expiration=1565728746&hwt=3a68626b4ca706823c1ca7e685b17e4f) is a good overview, too.

Comment: @Geremia [Here](https://marshner.christendom.edu/?p=950) is a very good article by William Marshner on the topic we discussed.

Answer (score 3):

Those who are validly baptized are Christians.  From *Lumen Gentium*, the Dogmatic Constitution on the Church from the Second Vatican Council:

> 15. The Church recognizes that in many ways she is linked with those who, being baptized, are honored with the name of Christian, though they do not profess the faith in its entirety or do not preserve unity of communion with the successor of Peter. (14*) For there are many who honor Sacred Scripture, taking it as a norm of belief and a pattern of life, and who show a sincere zeal. They lovingly believe in God the Father Almighty and in Christ, the Son of God and Saviour. (15*) They are consecrated by baptism, in which they are united with Christ. They also recognize and accept other sacraments within their own Churches or ecclesiastical communities. Many of them rejoice in the episcopate, celebrate the Holy Eucharist and cultivate devotion toward the Virgin Mother of God.(16*) They also share with us in prayer and other spiritual benefits. Likewise we can say that in some real way they are joined with us in the Holy Spirit, for to them too He gives His gifts and graces whereby He is operative among them with His sanctifying power. Some indeed He has strengthened to the extent of the shedding of their blood. In all of Christ's disciples the Spirit arouses the desire to be peacefully united, in the manner determined by Christ, as one flock under one shepherd, and He prompts them to pursue this end. (17*) Mother Church never ceases to pray, hope and work that this may come about. She exhorts her children to purification and renewal so that the sign of Christ may shine more brightly over the face of the earth.

Comment: You may find that some documents conflict this answer. _Trent_ curses anyone who practices the Sacraments differently than prescribed, and so while this document mentions that some practice them, those who practice them outside of the Catholic Church are not only invalidated, they are cursed.