# What is the wording used for Christadelphian baptism?

Tags: catholicism, baptism, biblical-unitarian, christadelphians

The top answer currently on the question [Would a person baptized by a Biblical Unitarian church be considered a Christian by the Catholic Church?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91153/would-a-person-baptized-by-a-biblical-unitarian-church-be-considered-a-christian) links to a document [Valid baptisms reference list](https://d2y1pz2y630308.cloudfront.net/15206/documents/2017/4/Valid%20Baptisms%20Reference%20List.pdf) from the Catholic diocese of Columbus which lists which denominational baptisms the diocese considers to be valid.

One that is considered invalid is the Christadelphian baptism. Part of the requirement for a valid baptism by the Catholic Church is the phrase

> "I baptize you in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the
> Holy Spirit"

which is very similar to Matthew 28:19's

> "Therefore, go and make disciples of all the nations, baptizing them
> in the name of the Father and the Son and the Holy Spirit"

What is the wording Christadelphians use when baptizing?

Comment: I don't think that the Columbus Diocese list of invalid baptisms necessarily reflects universal teaching - nor would any diocese say that something on their website does. Usually Bishops well mention this kind of stuff in their letters, they are guidance for a particular diocese.  I think the Congregation for the Doctrine of the Faith (Vatican office) would be the official source for a list like this.

Comment: @PeterTurner Thanks for this - yes, I think you're probably right. I find it a bit strange this information isn't clearer publicly, given the importance of it for Catholic sacraments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is misleading.

I'm Christadelphian and been to many Christadelphian baptisms. There isn't an exact phase you MUST use, it's not treated as some sort of magical incantation in the sense you have to get exactly right or it's not a valid baptism. I've heard several phrases used although can't recall what they were exactly right now. Generally though it's either, "I baptize you in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit", or some minor variation on those words.

The article quoted in the other answer evaluates different alternative options and the author offers a couple of suggestions as quoted. I've never heard those suggestions actually used in practice, they may have been used by someone at some time. However there is a good chance that they never have and this was purely an academic exercise by the author.

Generally though we put far more emphasis on what what the baptismal candidate believes, than the exact wording at the moment they are fully immersed.

Likewise I would have thought the fact we don't believe in the trinity (and therefore the Athanasian Creed) would be a bigger issue for the Catholic Church than the exact wording at baptism?

Comment: > would be a bigger issue for the Catholic Church than the exact wording at baptism
It is, but the words used are part of the consideration. Using the right words, but with a different intention/understanding would not be recognized (E.g. Mormonism). Using the wrong words but believing in the Trinity would likewise not be accepted.

Comment: I guess it goes without saying, but if Catholics and Christadelphians agreed, then there wouldn't be two separate denominations.

You wouldn't get a true Christadelphian (one who agrees with the BASF, our foundational statement of faith and a prerequisite for fellowship... or a very similar statement of faith from one of the Christadelphian offshoots), going into a Catholic Church and expecting to join in the services.

Christadelphians came out of the reformation era, where many people decided Catholic teaching didn't match scripture. There is separation for a reason, it goes both ways.

Comment: For Catholics, the question about valid baptism matters less for attending services (Catholics don't prohibit non-Catholics from attending), but rather for conversions. If a person is validly baptized, then becoming Catholic doesn't require another baptism

Comment: Each Christadelphian Ecclesia (local group) is autonomous, so make up their own minds to extend fellowship or not by allowing a visitor to break bread and wine. Anyone can attend, just not take the emblems unless they are baptised and members of an ecclesia acknowledged by the one your attending. Generally this is taken on trust, and visitors sign a book at the back with their names and the name of the ecclesia they belong to... from which the president of the meeting will read from to welcome the visitors and invite them to partake of the emblems.

Comment: It's possible to have been baptised as a Christadelphian and then change your mind on certain core beliefs... or behavioural issues. At which point some ecclesias would not accept you to take the emblems, but perhaps another would. Each Ecclesia is autonomous and makes up it's own mind.

Answer (score 2):

**What is the wording used for Christadelphian baptism?**

[***We baptize you into the name of the Father manifested in the Son through the power of the holy spirit.”***](https://tidings.org/articles/the-baptismal-formula/)

> With these considerations before us, an appropriate baptismal formula would be either: “…upon this your public confession before these witnesses, ***we baptize you into the name of the Lord Jesus Christ for the remission of your sins and the hope of eternal life.***” Or we could say: “…***we baptize you into the name of the Father which has been manifested in the Son through the power of the holy spirit for the remission of sins and hope of eternal life***.”