# Was there any controversy over the validity of sacraments during the Arian Controversy?

Tags: sacraments, arianism

During the Arian controversy, were sacraments (especially baptisms and/or ordinations) performed by one side or the other considered invalid by their opponents? Were there any "official" rulings on the matter by the leading figures on either side (especially popes)?